# is TransformerFactoryImpl of Xalan is thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, xalan

Is the class `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl` thread safe? Or do I have to a keep local copy for each thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Xalan Transform API](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/trax.html#pattern-TransformerFactory) document:

> A TransformerFactory may not perform mulitple concurrent operations.

Comment: I wonder if this note is dictated only by presence of setter methods or something else.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly doesn't look thread safe looking at the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/xalan/processor/TransformerFactoryImpl.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looking closely in the source suggests that it should be thread safe in case you don't call setter methods after first initialization.